# findNavController().popBackStack() is false if I setStartDestination graph

Tags: android, kotlin

I used setStartDestination via code, but when call popBackStack(), there was no action.

```
val graph = R.id.any_destination
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController
    val navGraph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav)
    navGraph.setStartDestination(graph)
    navController.graph = navGraph
```

when i check log, popBackStack() is false.

Please help how to back previous with call popBackStack(), thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your current code has no `fragment` or `activity` in the back stack. For this reason it returns `false`.

The `setStartDestination` method does not add any values ​​to the back stack.

First you need to go to a `destination`. `popBackStack` can then be used.

I recommend using at least 1 `navigate()`.